# Show Raw Contents of update-alternatives

Tags: command-line, 16.04, update-alternatives

I'm wondering if there's a way to show the raw contents of `sudo update-alternatives --config <resource>`?

I've been doing quite a lot of troubleshooting getting some installs correct and I cannot remember what I entered to get it working properly. For eg. *I think* I ran this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/bin/javaws 100
```

But I'm not sure about the first argument after `--install` and doing `sudo update-alternatives --config javaws` does not show me that part of the query in the output.

```
  Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/bin/javaws   100       auto mode
  1            /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_251/bin              1         manual mode
  2            /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/javaws       100       manual mode
* 3            /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/bin/javaws   100       manual mode
```

I looked at the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/sv/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) but couldn't find anything promising.

**TL;DR** - is there a way of getting the raw contents of these connections? (i.e. *what I entered*)

Comment: the raw state file is placed in */var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/* (and the links in /etc/alternatives/)

Comment: @bac0n although it didn't show me all the different options I've entered for the first argument, *it does* show me the active one. Post it as the answer and I'll approve. Thanks.